# Is it possible to override only one ViewState of a native control?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I don't want to override everything, but one of the viewstates needs to be changed in a native XAML control to suit the needs of my application. Is it possible to override just one or do they all need to be overridden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must override the style/template to accomplish this.